# regex french city zip codes

Tags: r, regex

I need to detect/extract values from french city zip codes

Expected results :

- numbers after first parenthesis and before space.
- numbers before second parenthesis and after space.

ex :

```
Abancourt (70 2 05 002)
Abancourt (76 666)
```

expected result :

```
70002  
76666
```

What I tried : numbers after first parenthesis and before space.

```
dummy<- c("Abancourt (70 2 05 002)", "Abancourt (76 666)")
grep(pattern ="[0-9]{2}" , dummy)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to match the 2 digits after the `(` and the 3 digits before the `)`, capture as a group and in the replacement use the backreference of the captured groups

```
as.numeric(sub(".*[(]([0-9]{2}).*([0-9]{3})[)]", "\\1\\2", dummy))
#[1] 70002 76666
```